# Bare metal LB with Kube ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am running 3 Kube nodes behind an HA Proxy instance. HA proxy ( not in the kube cluster ) has the external IP address and points to the 3 Kube nodes running Nginx as the ingress controller on Node Ports. I would like the Nginx proxy service to reflect the IP address HA proxy has been assigned in the EXTERNAL-IP field, ultimately so External DNS can pickup this external IP and create the required DNS entries in order for me ot access any new services. Is there any way to get this field updated by a DNS query? Something that would query the URL pointing to HA proxy and then set the EXTERNAL-IP field to the result?

`URL ( Dynamic DNS ) -> IP ( Dynamic) -> HA Proxy -> 3 Kube hosts ( NodePort )`

Thanks!